# A world where mainstream science exhausts all manmade & natural explanations of UFO phenomena

Tags: aliens

- The objects must demonstrate technological feats beyond human-conception.
- The objects enter through wormholes on Earth, not in Space. (The objects are never observed coming from space. They literally pop up out of nowhere)
- The objects are usually probes. This means we won't have a lot of chances to communicate.
- The objects cannot be captured.

> Create a world, with limited chances to observe the phenomenon and a
> short time-window to communicate to prove it can't be human.
>
> Create another world, where we fail to communicate with ET. But it
> must be proven that the objects are not human technology.
>
> And, the science-community has no choice but to accept it.

With such limited opportunity to observe, how do scientists find a way to prove its aliens?

Comment: The Probes aren't ideal for communicating. How? That's supposed to be beyond our knowledge & reasoning. This is ET, not human reasoning here.

Comment: Upvote because I was laughing pretty hard just now.

Comment: Sounds like fairy mischief to me, it's the wee folk I tells yer.

Comment: Perhaps the probe might hover for 15 minutes above a University?

Answer (score 3):

**Easy as pie!**

1: Objects appear and disappear out of nowhere.  That is a fine feat beyond human conception.  Although maybe it is within human conception because magicians do that with rabbits and hot assistants and stuff.

2: Yes, wormholes, out of nowhere, got it.

3:  No chance to communicate.  They appear and disappear within milliseconds.

4:  No chance to capture - yes; see 1.

Prove it cant be human: these objects are all different kinds of live alien creatures that gurn and sputter for the milliseconds they are here.  Slow motion cameras catch them in action.  Nothing like them around Earth, appearing and disappearing notwithstanding.

Fail to communicate - sure.  Even if some secret human group had the appear and disappear tech where are they getting these alien creatures?  Plus they are gone so quick there is no time to chat.  On the slomo they seem pretty surprised also.

Science has to accept it: yes, because these things show up absolutely everywhere, hundreds of thousands of times a day, all over the world.  In any given classroom you can be confident of seeing one at least once a week.  Scientists make trading cards depicting the various creatures.  Collect them all!  Sales support scientific research to cure gluons of their glueyness.

Comment: It would be interesting if the probe just hovered above NYC for a week. Would be a great opportunity to observe!

Comment: @TravisWells  - yes but "limited chances to observe"!  Your NY probe will need to be for a third scenario.